Is there a relation between sample & hold capacitor value and system clock speed?
Sometimes when looking at obscure and inadequate datasheets for various components I'll find an IC that has a pin for a sample & hold capacitor to connect to ground, but often times these datasheets are often lacking an application circuit, let alone a value range for said sample & hold capacitor in the recommended operating conditions or absolute maximum ratings. These are usually out-of-production components that use some sort of ADC/DAC. However, what these datashaeets usually have, is an operating range for the system clock speed.
So, I'm wondering if there is a relation between the sample & hold capacitor value and the system clock speed, and if there is a way to determine this? I've tried to search for this, and I've found a couple of Analog Devices documents that sort of mention a relationship between the two, but I've yet to find an explanation or a way to figure that out.
What, for example, would be an appropriate capacitor value for a 1MHz system clock? 4MHz? Does sample rate play a factor in this?

The relation of capacitance to clock speed is such that given the amount of clocks the capacitor is charged, it must charge to some close enough level so the resulting conversion does not have more error than you want.
The capacitor must charge through some switch or mux which has some resistance, and also via the source impedance which must be low enough.
That's why many ADCs like the ones built into MCUs may have configurable ADC clock, configurable sampling time, and configurable result in bits, all depend on through what source impedance the internal capacitor is charged and how precise result you want and how quickly or slowly you want it.
So in the end it's about RC charging the capacitor, the longer it is charged, the closer the sampled voltage is to the actual voltage.
But without a specific IC and knowledge how it works, there cannot be given a capacitor value based on some arbitrary system clock for an unknown system.

Thank you for that explanation! The YM7128 is a good example (I've been revisiting old Sound Blaster/AdLib stuff lately), where there's a picture of an application circuit but no values listed there or in the rest of the datasheet, but the nominal clock frequency is 7.16MHz (some schematics I've seen that use the YM7128 have something like a 3900pF/3.9nF capacitor for the CHA pin, but I wasn't sure how they figured out that value).

All of the sampling ADCs that I've seen run the input pin straight to the sampling switch, without any buffering.  So the sampling artifacts depend on the sampling time (which probably depends on the ADC clock), the settling characteristics of your buffer circuit, any charge injection from the switch, and for external capacitors, the behavior of the capacitor.  I'm not surprised that a datasheet would be thin on detail -- this is the stuff of applications notes and conversations with applications engineers.

@paraparabolic Ah the reverb chip used as add-on for Adlib Gold. Wrote an emulator for that, never released it. Anyway, the mux between output channels is on for certain period of sampling rate, so it depends on clock and how long is the period of capacitor needing to hold the value without droop etc. I recall reverse-engineering some of the values from a photo but it just relates to analog performance. Plastic or NP0/C0G would be reasonable output hold caps in the 1nF..10nF range maybe.
